# How can I create a backup disk image of a MacBook before I start the first-run process?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Is there any way to create an image of a brand new "unconfigured" MacBook?  I want to get an image of this box before the OS installs just in case I have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to another Mac and the necessary cable, you could boot your MacBook in Target Disk Mode (hold down the <kbd>T</kbd> key when powering up). Connect via Firewire or Thunderbolt to another Mac. The drive on the machine in Target Disk Mode can then be cloned.

Answer (score 0):

The Macbooks include what's called a "Recovery Partition". This partition allows you to troubleshoot and repair boot issues as well as do what's known as an "Internet Recovery", which will do a clean install of Mountain Lion as if it were clean out of the box.

Please see this link for more information: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718

Comment: These are valid answers once I have logged into the box and done an initial configuration.  I want to get a disk image before first configuration.  Clonezilla does Linux and Windows images, Ghost, Acronis, Paragon and other packages do Windows images only.  Is there a Mac package that provides the same capability

Comment: Actually both answers bypass the initial configuration so you should be able to get a clean image with both.